# Finding encryption type of hash

Tags: passwords, password-cracking

Is it possible to find encryption type of a hash with a salt?

I have my other password in same encryption type, with the hash from that and the password, if that helps.

```
$2y$10$fOEjqK7NFkTiM6nWUFIcqenKxwmK7vwDfwjTB0wqsi44dR/VisZr2
```

Above is the password I have lost, and I'm trying to find the encryption type to help me find my password.

This is the same salt, same encryption and the password I used for it, so possibly this can help

Comment: can u specify which application is storing these passwords? The fields across the dollar ($) sign specify information about the hash such as hash algorithm , salt etc.

Comment: VeraCrypt is the application. I lost this password to one my drives :( I have this encrypted version!

Comment: bcrypt password hashes can not be decrypted because 1. They are not encryption and 2. It is a one-way function. 3. It requires a substantial amount of CPU time for each attempt. 4. If recovering the bcrypt generated password was easy (or even hard) it would not be a secure method. 5. A hash is not encryption. 6. How will knowing the "type of hash" help?

Comment: While the headline question can be answered, you can not recover your password this way. Hashing is one way.

Answer (score 4):

`2y` indicates [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt), specifically PHP's fixed implementation. `10` is the cost, `fOEjqK7NFkTiM6nWUFIcqe` is the salt, and `nKxwmK7vwDfwjTB0wqsi44dR/VisZr2` is the hash.

Comment: Thankyou for clarity, I'm going to try to use this information to help me in the process of hiring someone to help me decrypt my password to my drive. I am using hashcat myself but likely will get  nowhere :(

Comment: As far as I'm aware veracrypt has never supported bcrypt, and even if it did it wouldn't be storing the hash like that.

Comment: bcrypt password hashes can not be decrypted because 1. They are not encryption and 2. It is a one-way function. 3. It requires a substantial amount of CPU time for each attempt. 4. If recovering the bcrypt generated password was easy (or even hard) it would not be a secure method.